# How to use finite sets represented as lists in attributes of a class in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm using ListSet extension from the standard library of Coq, to use finite sets as attributes of a class:

```
Require Import ListSet.
Class aux := {
  attribute1: set;
  attribute2: set -> set;
  }.
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Error: In environment
aux : Type
The term "set" has type "Type -> Type" which should be Set, Prop or Type.
```

I don't understand why this is happening. (I'm new to Coq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coq is telling you that `set` is not a type but instead of type `Type -> Type` meaning it takes a type as argument.

If you look at the definition: https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.ListSet.html
you can see that it indeed requires a parameter.
So the type you want to consider is `set A` for some type `A` and in fact it is just the type `list A`, what the `ListSet` module brings, are operations on `set A` that preserve invariants such as the fact that you don't have twice the same element.

Perhaps these are not the sets you had in mind.